# Show hidden part of an View with pulling it by gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, swipe-gesture

i want to design my interface like this: on top of a screen user can see a picture (image view), in bottom might be a view with buttons (or other control elements). When screen load first i want to show an image and 60% of view that contains buttons, then, user pull bottom view up with gesture, and therefore it hide image view, revealing view full size. Then user can hide it again to 60% of "true" size with pulling bottom with fingers.

Here i tried to post a screen that can explain it visually (because I'm afraid you might not understand what i want to).

I want to know how to implement it, any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you want to imitate something like the photo browser in Facebook ios app ? User being able to pull up the text to view it ?
Do you want the user to be able to pan the bottom view (move it up/down with their finger), or do you want the user to be able to tap it to reveal the full view and re-tap to hide it?

Comment: Just pull it up with finger, then when user reach top of screen it fixed on it when tap released, then he can pull down to first state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add swipe gesture to your bottom view as shown below.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *ges =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];
[bottomView addGestureRecognizer:ges];
```

**-- swipe handler --**

```
-(void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGes{
    if(swipeGes.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            //set frame of bottom view to top of screen (show 100%)
            bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, bottomView.frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
    else if (swipeGes.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            //set frame of bottom view to bottom of screen (show 60%)
            bottomView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, bottomView.frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you save me a lot of time :)